# UDP timeout detector

Tags: go, udp

Camera streaming app for the pizero, hobby project.

I want the cam to be sending frames only if there is an active client on the other end.

For this purpose the cam is listening on a port for client keep alive messages. If no messages are received for 5 seconds, camera stops sending frames.

I built the detector but I am not confident I did a really good job. Mainly because timeout detection is not consistent. Cam will detect a timeout somewhere between 5 and 30s.

Advice on how to improve is very much appreciated.

EDIT:

It was pointed out that the code was not working as I intended. Feedback in the comment section helped me fix the inconsistency.

Code sample is now working.

```
package server

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type session struct {
    Conn     *net.UDPConn
    Message  chan string
    Password string
    Address  chan *net.UDPAddr
}

type monitor struct {
    Conn        *net.UDPConn
    IsLive      bool
    Kill        chan bool
    LastMsg     time.Time
    ListenTick  *time.Ticker
    MonitorTick *time.Ticker
}

func newMonitor(port string) *monitor {
    return &monitor{
        Conn:        bindAddress(port),
        IsLive:      false,
        Kill:        make(chan bool),
        ListenTick:  time.NewTicker(time.Second),
        MonitorTick: time.NewTicker(time.Second),
    }
}

func (m *monitor) listen() {
    //program hangs here if no ticker is used. why???
    for range m.ListenTick.C {

        if !m.IsLive {
            continue
        }

        buffer := make([]byte, 10)

        n, err := m.Conn.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        if len(buffer[0:n]) > 0 {
            m.LastMsg = time.Now()
        }
    }
}

func (m *monitor) detectTimeOut() {
    for range m.MonitorTick.C {

        if !m.IsLive {
            continue
        }

        if time.Since(m.LastMsg) > time.Second*5 {
            fmt.Println("No response")
            m.IsLive = false
            m.Kill <- true
        }
    }
}

func Run(port, password *string, frame <-chan []byte, done <-chan bool) {
    session := newSession(port, password)
    go session.listenForClients()
    fmt.Println("Listening for clients on: ", session.Conn.LocalAddr())
    defer session.Conn.Close()

    heartBeatPort := stringPortToInt(*port)
    monitor := newMonitor(fmt.Sprintf(":%v", heartBeatPort+1))
    go monitor.listen()
    go monitor.detectTimeOut()
    defer monitor.Conn.Close()

    var address *net.UDPAddr

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Stopping server")
            return
        case address = <-session.Address:
            fmt.Println("New client authenticated from address: ", address)
            monitor.IsLive = true
            monitor.LastMsg = time.Now()
        case f := <-frame:
            switch address {
            case nil:
                continue
            default:
                _, err := session.Conn.WriteToUDP(f, address)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err)
                }
            }
        case <-monitor.Kill:
            fmt.Println("Client timed out")
            address = nil
        default:
            continue
        }
    }
}

func newSession(port, password *string) *session {
    return &session{
        Conn:     bindAddress(*port),
        Message:  make(chan string),
        Password: *password,
        Address:  make(chan *net.UDPAddr),
    }
}

func (s session) listenForClients() {
    for {
        buf := make([]byte, 1024)
        n, addr, err := s.Conn.ReadFromUDP(buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        m := buf[0:n]

        if s.Password == "" {
            s.Address <- addr
            continue
        }

        if s.authenticate(string(m), addr) {
            s.Address <- addr
        }
    }
}

func (s *session) authenticate(message string, address *net.UDPAddr) bool {
    if s.Password == message {
        _, _ = s.Conn.WriteToUDP([]byte("ok"), address)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func bindAddress(port string) *net.UDPConn {
    laddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    listenAddr, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", laddr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return listenAddr
}

func stringPortToInt(number string) int {
    n, err := strconv.Atoi(number[1:])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return n
}
```

Comment: Hi, it seems that your code isn't working as expected. If so, it isn't a great fit for CodeReview (it is probably better suited on the main site of Stack Overflow). I would happily help you there ! (Hint: the two `for range m.Tick.C` read from the same channel : only one of them will get the generated ticks)

Comment: Once your code works as expected, you are welcome to open a new question here, asking for a review on how to improve the code style or the performance :-)

Comment: @oliverpool Hey thanks for the great hint. I added a second ticker for the `detector` loop. I edited the code on my question to reflect it. Code is now working as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the timeout detection, you could simplify your logic, by making use of the [`SetReadDeadline`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn). Thanks to this, your timers are not needed anymore.

Your monitor would then look like this:

```
type monitor struct {
    Conn *net.UDPConn
    Kill chan bool
}

func newMonitor(port string) *monitor {
    return &monitor{
        Conn: bindAddress(port),
        Kill: make(chan bool),
    }
}

func (m *monitor) detectTimeOut(delay time.Duration) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 10)
    m.Conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(delay))
    for {
        n, err := m.Conn.Read(buffer)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        if n > 0 {
            // something was read before the deadline
            // let's delay the deadline
            m.Conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(delay))
        }

        if nerr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && nerr.Timeout() {
            // Timeout error
            fmt.Println("No response")
            m.Kill <- true
            return
        }
    }
}
```

And since this method returns on timeout, it needs to be launched every time an new address listens:

```
heartBeatPort := stringPortToInt(*port)
monitor := newMonitor(fmt.Sprintf(":%v", heartBeatPort+1))
defer monitor.Conn.Close()

var address *net.UDPAddr

for {
    select {
    case <-done:
        fmt.Println("Stopping server")
        return
    case address = <-session.Address:
        fmt.Println("New client authenticated from address: ", address)
        go monitor.detectTimeOut(time.Second)
    case f := <-frame:
        switch address {
        case nil:
            continue
        default:
            _, err := session.Conn.WriteToUDP(f, address)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }
    case <-monitor.Kill:
        fmt.Println("Client timed out")
        address = nil
    default:
        continue
    }
}
```

---

This code code should work (I can't test it), but the way the "address" is managed could be more elegant (for example to manage in case of multiple listeners).

Here is a proposition, where each listener is in charge of forwarding the frames to a particular address, via a given connection.

The main loop is in charge of maintaining a slice of all those listeners and forward every frame to all of them (without blocking).

With this code, we see clearly, that only 2 connections are used (monitor and session), which might not be the best idea (I don't know how they behave when concurrent goroutines write data at the same time). To fix this, you should simply adapt the main loop.

```
type listener struct {
    frames chan []byte
}

func NewListener() listener {
    return listener{
        frames: make(chan []byte),
    }
}

func (l listener) forwardFrames(conn *net.UDPConn, addr *net.UDPAddr) {
    for f := range l.frames {
        _, err := conn.WriteToUDP(f, addr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}

func (l listener) newFramesChannel() chan<- []byte {
    return l.frames
}

func (l listener) detectTimeOut(conn net.Conn, delay time.Duration, deadListener chan chan []byte) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 10)
    conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(delay))
    for {
        n, err := conn.Read(buffer)

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        if n > 0 {
            // something was read before the deadline
            // let's delay the deadline
            conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(delay))
        }

        if nerr, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && nerr.Timeout() {
            // Timeout error
            fmt.Println("No response")
            deadListener <- l.frames
            return
        }
    }

}

func Run(port, password *string, frame <-chan []byte, done <-chan bool) {
    session := newSession(port, password)
    go session.listenForClients()
    fmt.Println("Listening for clients on: ", session.Conn.LocalAddr())
    defer session.Conn.Close()

    heartBeatPort := stringPortToInt(*port)
    monitor := newMonitor(fmt.Sprintf(":%v", heartBeatPort+1))
    defer monitor.Conn.Close()

    listeners := make([](chan<- []byte), 0)
    deadListener := make(chan chan []byte, 0)

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Stopping server")
            for _, l := range listeners {
                close(l)
            }
            return
        case address := <-session.Address:
            fmt.Println("New client authenticated from address: ", address)
            l := NewListener()
            go l.forwardFrames(session.Conn, address)
            go l.detectTimeOut(monitor.Conn, time.Second, deadListener)
            listeners = append(listeners, l.newFramesChannel())
        case f := <-frame:
            for _, l := range listeners {
                // Send frame to each listener, without waiting
                select {
                case l <- f:
                default:
                }
            }
        case l := <-deadListener:
            // remove l from the listeners slice
            for i := 0; i < len(listeners); i++ {
                if listeners[i] == l {
                    listeners[i] = listeners[len(listeners)-1]
                    listeners = listeners[:len(listeners)-1]
                    close(l)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```